# SKPhysics node and how send BOOL to correct object

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

//very likely a nubby mistake...
collisions work if drag tile hits TargetNodeCatagoryT1
but how to set BOOL on the hit object?

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == DragTileCategory &&
    secondBody.categoryBitMask == TargetNodeCatagoryT1 ){

   TargetNode *hitNode = (TargetNode *) secondBody.node;
    hitNode.hasHitT1 = YES; <<this crashes app
    but I wish to send BOOl back...
}
```

**ERROR LOG:**
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SKSpriteNode setHasHitT1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

```
Thank's Knight0fDragon You are right, the "hitNode" are SKSpriteNodes 
nested within the TargetNode class - each TargetClass has 3 targets,


 BOOLS are declared in .h and synthesised in .m   
    @interface TargetNode : SKNode 
    BOOL hasHitTarget1;
    BOOL hasHitTarget2;
    BOOL hasHitTTarget3;

 //later
    @property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL hasHitTarget1;
    @property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL hasHitTarget2;
    @property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL hasHitTarget3;

 @implementation TargetNode
 @synthesize hasHitTarget1,hasHitTarget2,hasHitTarget3;

 -(id)initWithImageNamed:(NSString*)imageName labelText:(NSString*)labelText
 other stuff here....then

   hasHitTarget1 = NO;
   hasHitTarget2 = NO;
   hasHitTarget3 = NO;
```

[image]

**Got it working by:**
attaching the physicsBody to the label I want to change later
(the physicsBody was a bit like a marker if I could locate the  secondBody.node I would be able to change the text... probably this isn't the best way - but it worked for my purposes :)

//attaching the physicsBody
e.g  T1label.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize...

//finding the object secondBody

In didMakeContact
        secondBody.categoryBitMask == TargetNodeCatagoryT1 ){

```
    //Convert second body into useable object 
    SKLabelNode *hitNode = (SKLabelNode *) secondBody.node;

    //change text
    hitNode.text =@"test";

    NSLog(@"TargetNode Name@%@",hitNode.name);

    //Test type of object
    NSLog(@"hitNode isMemberOfClass  TargetNode: %@", [hitNode isMemberOfClass:[TargetNode class]] ? @"YES":@"NO");
    NSLog(@"hitNode isMemberOfClass  SKSpriteNode: %@", [hitNode isKindOfClass:[SKLabelNode class]] ? @"YES":@"NO");  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is failing because your `hitNode` IS NOT a `TargetNode`, even though you are claiming it is.  Use `[hitNode isKindOfClass:]` or `[hitNode isMemberOfClass:]` to validate what `hitNode` is.

The only other problem is you did not create your property correctly, or it did not synthesis for you, and `setHasHitT1` never got created thus `hitNode.hasHitT1 = YES;` fails

Comment: Hi Knight0fDragon, thanks, added above code
the Hitnode is a SKSpriteNode inside of the TargetNode Class
BOOL doesn't work -have added code maybe you can see where I have made mistake...

Comment: whoa whoa whoa, why is targetnode your physicscontactdelegate,  your scene should be doing this

Comment: well your TargetNode needs to have a physics body attached to it,  Target node is an SKNode,  but your message says SKSpriteNode, so I have no idea what you are doing to help with the rest.  You need to visit tutorials to learn and understand how this work

Comment: SKNode "TargetNode" has 3 SKSpriteNodes "T1,T2,T3" with physics bodies attached to them

Comment: well then you need to somehow get the to Target node from T1 T2 T3,  if they are children, then do .parent